# cURL a SWF file

Tags: php, flash

I need some help, I am trying to load a SWF file through a PHP cURL - which isn't working.

I tried using the 'CURLOPT_URL' to go the .swf itself and to a php file that has the swf embedded... no dice on either.

What I am trying to do...

I am trying to create a dynamic image file, so the img src will be a php file. This PHP will cURL/Ping/Load the swf file or a page with that swf file. Once the swf file is loaded, it saves a image to the server.

Then my php file readfile's the new image.

Is there a way to load the swf file through something like CURL or even a web service API to that remotely loads a URL?

Any help would be great!! :)

EDIT:  I read this:  [Loading swf from a seperate file server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907323/loading-swf-from-a-seperate-file-server?rq=1)

So the SWF file has to be open/viewed by a browser.

Is there a service/API/library that can simulate that sort of thing?

Comment: you're making mirror of that swf, why no using the mirror link in html flash ?

Answer (score 0):

It can be much easier than that.

to save the swf to the server, use

```
file_put_contents("/path/to/swf/storage/image.swf", "http://have-a-swf--mate.com/swf.swf");
```

and as for putting the swf on your page, check this out: 
[how to put flash (.swf) in a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418446/how-to-put-flash-swf-in-a-page)

Alternatively, you can forgo saving the .swf on your server and just:

```
<object width="650" height="140">
  <param name="movie" value="exactheader.swf">
  <embed src="<?php echo $calculated-URL-for-swf-file ?>" width="650" height="140"> </embed>
</object>
```

Comment: Hey man - thanks for the help. :)

Not sure this is what I need though. I am trying to run the swf file in the background (not through an embed/object tag), because the php file would be run through a img tag:

<img src="runflashfile.php" />

Comment: I am ethically obligated to remind you flash is a bad idea. But, the file_put_contents will save the file for you, at least.

Comment: lol thank you! I am trying to avoid using GD for dynamic image creation.

Comment: Good call -- GD is phasing out, anyway - you could also look into imagemagick --- Oh, but yeah - cURL is more for examining headers and sending GET/POST data- and other, obscure stuff. I've never seen it used in place of what is `wget` in bash - but I'm sure you can find a way to do it with cURL - but I'm also sure that just saving a file to a server with cURL is hammering a framing nail with a sledgehammer.